# result too large c++ sockets

Tags: network-programming

I am getting an error an `bind()` with the value `34` (Result too large), can anyone help?

```
 void Connect(string address, unsigned short port){         
            memset(&server2, 0, sizeof(server2));
            server2.sin_family = AF_INET;  
            server2.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(address.c_str());  
            server2.sin_port = htons(port);  

            desc2 = ::socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);            
            if(desc2 == -1) {            
                cout << "Error in Socket()" << endl;    
            }

            if((::bind(desc2,(sockaddr*)&server2, sizeof(server2))) == -1) {                        
                cout << "Error in Bind() " <<  errno << endl;
            }

            if((::connect(desc2, (sockaddr*)&server2, sizeof(server2))) > 0) {                      
                cout << "Error in Connect()" << endl;    
            }
            cout << "YOU ARE CONNECTED TO " << address << " ON PORT " << port << endl;              
}
```

PS: I got this error 1 year ago too,the problem was simple i had write something bad when initializing the socket address, where to connect, but now again i have no clue where I made a mistake.

Comment: its in dots notation,if it is like a domain,it works ....strange

Comment: pointing out an error: connect returns 0 on success, use `== 0`. I would also change -1 to `SOCKET_ERROR`

Comment: i set both to SOCKET_ERROR. Btw do i really need to call bind when connecting,or only when i am listening to connection(server part)?

Comment: why are u binding and then connecting? `bind` is used with `listen` and `accept` for servers, `connect` is used for clients

Comment: that is why i ask myself.so i dont need it.

Comment: well are you a server or a client?

Comment: well i am proxy server,and in Accept() i call Connect() so basically i am a client and binding is for servers,corect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I don't know what caused your problem exactly to return that type of result.*

You said you were a proxy server, so you are listening for incoming connections.
Try this:

```
server2.sin_addr.s_addr = 0;
server2.sin_family = AF_INET;
server2.sin_port = htons(port);

desc2 = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);

// Puts the socket in listening mode, allowing 10 connection requests to queue.
bind(desc2, (sockaddr*)&server2, sizeof(server2));
listen(desc2, 10);

// Accepts the first connection request.
SOCKET accepted_socket = accept(desc2, NULL, NULL);
std::cout << "connection accepted!\n";
```

You will probably want to learn how to program asynchronously.

Comment: well,yes this is the server part,this works for me,but after this,i want to connect to the server that the cleint connected to me says.Like he says "connect to www.google.com" on port 80....and i must connect to google

Comment: That will require you to have two separate sockets. One of those sockets is your connection between you and the client, the other connection is between you and google. When your client tells you to "connect to google on port 80", you need to create another socket and connect to google... on port 80.

Comment: Yes the code that i post is the socket beetween me and google(descriptor desc2, struct sockaddr server2). The socket beetwen the cleint and me is (descriptor desc, sockaddr server).  Btw after i get this to work it comes the part with the threading(i guess that means asynchronously programming)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know *why* you're getting 'name too long' -- without seeing how `server2` was declared and defined, it's impossible to know for sure.

But I *do* know that calling `bind()` and then `connect()` on the same socket with the same address will fail -- `bind()` is assigning the *local* address to the socket, and `connect()` connects to the *remote* address. Giving the same address for both ends of the socket can only end badly.

Almost no protocols require `bind()` before `connect()`. (The exceptions would involve the "ports lower than 1024 can only be opened by root, so we can trust this connection" style of authentication, which hasn't been used in ages. Think [`rlogin`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rlogin).)

`bind()` makes most sense immediately before a `listen()` call. Clients will attempt to contact a server on a 'well-known port', and `bind()` is the mechanism you use to assign that name.